# Python fast way to save huge numpy array as lossless image (tiff)

Tags: python, image, numpy, tiff

I have a program that processes huge RGB images in the range of 30000x30000 px.

To load I use Pillow, which works good.
Then I process it with NumPy and then I need to save it lossless as tiff.

However, whether I'm using Pillow or OpenCV, this takes very long compared to the runtime of all the other stuff. I think this is because of the image compression. Without compression, the saving does not take long at all but my files are >2 GB.
I found the module tifffile but it takes just as long as OpenCV, unless I missed a parameter.

Is there a module that can compress faster? The ones I tried only use one CPU core.

It also seems, that it's faster on an intel machine with i7-9700k 16GB than on my PC with AMD Ryzen 5600X 32GB?

Here is the code I used to test:

```py
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import tifffile
import numpy as np
import time


arr = np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 255, size=(30000,30000,3), endpoint=True, dtype=np.uint8)

st = time.time()
Image.fromarray(arr).save("test_pil.tiff", compression="tiff_adobe_deflate")
print(f"Pil took {time.time()-st} s")

st = time.time()
cv2.imwrite("test_cv2.tiff", arr, params=(cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 32946))
print(f"Opencv took {time.time()-st} s")

st = time.time()
tifffile.imwrite("test_tifff.tiff", arr, compression="zlib", compressionargs={'level':5}, predictor=True, tile=(64,64))
print(f"Tifffile took {time.time()-st} s")
```

I know these also use different compression algorithms, but I haven't found matching parameters. This feature is generally very poorly documented.

Result (intel):

```
Pil took 32.01173210144043 s
Opencv took 60.46461296081543 s
Tifffile took 59.410102128982544 s
```

Comment: Have a try with `pyvips` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vips

Comment: @MarkSetchell sadly this is not faster and still only uses one core. Takes 37 Seconds

Comment: If you have many images to process, maybe you could do them in parallel with **GNU Parallel**, e.g. `parallel python3 processOne ::: *.tif`

Comment: Thanks, but it's only a single image at a time.

Comment: I don't know if specifying tiling would enable `vips` or `tifffile` to maybe go faster and compress tiles in parallel... `tifffile.imwrite(..., tile=(256,256), ...)`

Comment: 64x64 tiles are too small for efficiently multi-threading the compression. Use 256x256 or larger tiles and the latest version of tifffile and imagecodecs.

Comment: yes, increasing tile size worked! thank you so much.
How do I determine ideal tile sizes and parameters in general? A size of 512 didn't seem to improve speed.

Comment: tifffile uses [hard-coded minimum segment sizes](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/eb79f64e65fdd17fa5722dac9ce32ec6dd224f5d/tifffile/tifffile.py#L3626-L3682) below which multi-threading is disabled by default. You can override it with the `maxworkers` argument. The optimum depends on too many parameters (segment size, data compressibility, codec, codec parameters, memory bandwidth...) to generalize.

Comment: I see, thanks! Ill test a bit to see what fits my dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Mark Setchell and @cgohlkes advice, I specified the tile size to 256x256 for tifffile and that improved the processing speed by a lot.

```py
tifffile.imwrite(target_path, sat_map, compression="zlib", compressionargs={'level':5}, predictor=True, tile=(256,256))
```